# Postsharp and Fody Compatibility

Tags: postsharp, fody, fody-propertychanged

I am using the free edition of PostSharp extensively in a project. I would like to use the [PropertyChanged.Fody](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) addin to handle all the PropertyChanged Notifications automatically.

(I know that PostSharp offers a library for this, but it is not free, thus I would like to use Fody)

It appears that when I use both PostSharp and [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody) in a project, the debug symbol files goes out of sync with the source code. When I debug a project I can no longer properly step through code. It looks similar to when you attach a debugger in VS to a process where the source code is different than that of the executing binary.

If I disable either PostSharp or Fody, then debugging works immediately again.

Is it possible to use both PostSharp and Fody in the same project? Does this require special / extra configuration?

Comment: Debugging with PostSharp should work. They have done a great job fixing this in the past versions. Maybe there are some new issues with that. Stepping into a property that has an aspect applied should take you to the aspect first.